# Improve SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to improve this query, that works very well.

```
DECLARE     @timTimeout int, 
        @iniDate varchar(20), 
        @endDate varchar(20)            
SET         @iniDate = '2014-07-20 00:00:00'              
SET         @endDate = '2014-11-24 23:59:59'           
SET         @timTimeout = 4000                       

SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF

SELECT 
            'Approved (0200)' = ISNULL(SUM(CASE CodMsgIncome WHEN '0200' THEN 1 END), 0),
            'Approved Off (0220)' = ISNULL(SUM(CASE CodMsgIncome WHEN '0220' THEN 1 END), 0),
            'Cancel (0400)' = ISNULL(SUM(CASE CodMsgIncome WHEN '0400' THEN 1 END), 0),
            'Regret (0420)' = ISNULL(SUM(CASE CodMsgIncome WHEN '0420' THEN 1 END), 0),
            'TOTAL' = COUNT(*),
            'Time-outs' = ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(ms, DateMsgIncome, DateMsgSent) > @timTimeout THEN 1 END), 0),
            'Disponibility (%)' = (1 - CAST(ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(ms, DateMsgIncome, DateMsgSent) > @timTimeout THEN 1 END), 0) as money) / COUNT(*)) * 100
FROM Message (NOLOCK)
    WHERE DateMsgIncome BETWEEN @iniDate AND @endDate
            AND CodMsgIncome IN ('0200', '0220', '0400', '0420', '0800', '0900', '9080', '9085') 
            AND DescMsgIncome <> '0220'
```

Now, I have to prepare a report with Total data organized by month.

The output disered seems like this:

```
      Approved (0200) | Approved Off (0220) | Cancel | Total | Time-outs | Disponibility (%)
July | 35                   15                   12      62       0            100.00
.
.
.
```

EDIT:
It is only one table on my query.

```
  Table Message:
DateMsgIncome date,
DateMsgSent date,
CodMsgIncome varchar(4),
DescMsgIncome varchar(4),
CodMsgAnswer int.
```

Any suggestion is welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't get any errors, do you? In what way do you want to improve that query? Speed-wise, aesthetically, or what?

Comment: Well, I don't know how can I group data by month. This is the improve that I want on it.

Comment: It is vague, because you do not describe what table structure you have. How should we know how to group this by month when we do not even know which column to select that month from? (DateMsgIncome, DateMsgSent for example seem to be both DateTime columns)

Comment: Besides that, adding a grouping to a query is not what I would call an improvement, but more like a change request ;)

Comment: @DrCopyPaste TY. I got it... I will edit the question and add my table structure.

Comment: Guys... If I had to do everything and then post here, I didn't need you help. As you can see, there is an edit... showing my ONLY ONE table that holds the data.

Comment: Why are you defining your date variables as varchar? And if you are going to use table hints like NOLOCK (Which I generally discourage due to inaccurate results) you need to include the WITH keyword.

Comment: My dates are date type. Pay a little more attention on it please.

Comment: So add a GROUP BY the month of one of your two date columns. We don't know which one.

Comment: I said the variables. Why define variables as varchar when they should be date?

Comment: Oh. Because I want a specific range of time. Just for a limit.

Comment: @SeanLange how can I group? Their value is on a variable. Should I set an alias on the variable?

Comment: Point missed completely. I understand the usage. You defined the variables as varchar. Defined them as datetime.

Comment: On the variable???? What??? Each row in your table has a date column right? You need to group by Month(YourDateColumn). All you need to do is add another column for the month and group by it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran your query through a code formatter to help clean it up. I also change the variable declaration since you didn't seem to understand what I was saying. For the record, the way you had it coded you might have missed some rows in the last few milliseconds of the day.

I changed the DATEDIFF function to use the datepart name spelled out because it is just too easy use the wrong abbreviation and get it wrong. I also simplified the calculation for the last column. The cast to money was not needed if you change the 1 -  to 1.0 -. You should avoid using reserved words for object names and avoid spaces in column names. Let the front end do this kind of pretty formatting.

I also added the soon the be required WITH keyword when using table hints. (I would recommend understand what NOLOCK really means before using it).

```
DECLARE @timTimeout int
    , @iniDate date
    , @endDate date

SET @iniDate = '2014-07-20'              
SET @endDate = '2014-11-25'           
SET @timTimeout = 4000                       

SELECT MONTH(DateMsgIncome) as MyMonthColumn
    , 'Approved (0200)' = ISNULL(SUM(CASE CodMsgIncome WHEN '0200' THEN 1 END), 0)
    , 'Approved Off (0220)' = ISNULL(SUM(CASE CodMsgIncome WHEN '0220' THEN 1 END), 0)
    , 'Cancel (0400)' = ISNULL(SUM(CASE CodMsgIncome WHEN '0400' THEN 1 END), 0)
    , 'Regret (0420)' = ISNULL(SUM(CASE CodMsgIncome WHEN '0420' THEN 1 END), 0)
    , 'TOTAL' = COUNT(*)
    , 'Time-outs' = ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, DateMsgIncome, DateMsgSent) > @timTimeout THEN 1 END), 0)
    , 'Disponibility (%)' = (1.0 - ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, DateMsgIncome, DateMsgSent) > @timTimeout THEN 1 END), 0) / COUNT(*)) * 100
FROM [Message] WITH (NOLOCK) --Ack!!! I wouldn't let this fly on my system due to inconsistencies with this hint unless accuracy is not important (like 

WHERE DateMsgIncome >= @iniDate 
    AND DateMsgIncome < @endDate
    AND CodMsgIncome IN 
    (
        '0200'
        , '0220'
        , '0400'
        , '0420'
        , '0800'
        , '0900'
        , '9080'
        , '9085'
    ) 
    AND DescMsgIncome <> '0220'
GROUP BY MONTH(DateMsgIncome)
```

Comment: Its a very required table, I must to prevent a lock on it. That's the reason for a `nolock` on it. I'll test your answer. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I get that you don't want to lock it. I just often see that hint thrown around and the user has no real idea what it is doing. It can and will get missing and/or duplicate rows. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidlean/archive/2009/04/06/sql-server-nolock-hint-other-poor-ideas.aspx

Comment: It worked just as I need. I only adjust the `group by` after the `where` clause. Thank you for your help and your patience. I'm not good in SQL, but now, I'm the only one here to do this report. Thank you again.

Comment: Oh boy...I know better than that. I will edit my answer accordingly. :) Glad that worked for you.